# Backend for Hortonworks Data Platform (HDP)

Tags: hadoop, ldap, backend, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am looking into backend of Hortonworks (Hortonworks Data Platform) along with Ambari for managing hadoop cluster. Now my confusion about the backend over here. Backend for HDP means LDAP/Active directory setup with Kerberos or is it related to NoSql databases. Also as I am accessing it through Ambari which by default uses Postgressql. So, not able to understand which backend for HDP I need to look up for admin level tasks. Please can anybody suggest on it or direct me to some useful links to start with it.

Only found this article on HDP portal for ldap backend.
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.1/bk_security/content/enabling_LDAP_backend.html

Comment: You're using the work "backend" in too many contexts here. Authorization? Code language? Administration?

Comment: mainly in Administration.

Comment: LDAP user accounts are synced with the local Ambari database. The Hortonworks page (and the Ambari wiki) will be the two main sources of information

Answer (score 0):

Ambari backend is primarily a java application (but also partially consists of python scripts). You may study source code [here](https://github.com/apache/ambari/tree/trunk/ambari-server). 
Agents are written on python, you may find their source code at the same repo. 
All Ambari-related configuration&data like command history is stored into a database. By default Postres is used, but you may use other [databases](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.6.0.0/bk_ambari-administration/content/using_non-default_databases_-_ambari.html) as well.

HDP components are configured by Ambari (so their configuration is stored at Ambari DB), but how other runtime data is stored depends on particular component architecture.

Comment: Ambari's server backend is a combination of Java and Python, not only the agents are Python

Comment: Thanks, added clarification